# PostgreSQL + Big CSV

Tags: php, postgresql, csv, yii

Hi I need help or advice .
Currently I have the need to manage a table in a PostgreSQL database via CSV files with more than 500,000 records normally.
Through Yii Framework perform administrator for a person to do this task based on the COPY sql and works perfect.
But now a special need the server where the Web environment is different server Database administrator and therefore no longer works. According researched for the COPY statement is necessary that the file must be on the same server that runs COPY .

We tried to change the script taking as a basis the following library : https://github.com/goodby/csv
But not completely goes records .
Even instructing set_time_limit ( 0);
And I have my doubts whether this method is suitable.
What alternatives I have or what I could do in such a case , given my short experience would greatly appreciate any information indicating which can help me to solve this problem. A true professional and solve this problem ? I want to learn 
In advance thank you .
Stay tuned .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP you could use the function [pg_put_line](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-put-line.php) in combination with COPY tablename FROM STDIN. I have no idea about performance, but it is faster than many INSERT-statements. Maybe it works for you.

Comment: Thanks for your response , I will investigate .
Additionally I would ask .
What statement or method used to import records PgAdmin, did the process in this way and climbed faster and perfectly.